# $(h,k).(1,1)=(h\varphi(k)(1),k(1))$ what is $\varphi(k)$?

Tags: group-theory

I am working with:

Let $H$ and $K$ be groups and let $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ be the group of automorphisms of $H$ (under function composition).
Suppose also that we are given a homomorphism $\varphi: K \to \operatorname{Aut}(H)$.
The semidirect product of $H$ and $K$ with respect to $\varphi$, denoted by $H\rtimes K$, has as its underlying set the Cartesian
product $H \times K$. Multiplication is defined by
$$
(h_1, k_1)(h_2, k_2) = (h_1\varphi(k_1)(h_2), k_1k_2) 
\tag{1}
$$ 
where $\varphi(k_1)(h_2)$ is the automorphism $\varphi(k_1)$ applied to $h_2$.

I am trying to show that the identity is $(1,1)$ but when I calculate I get stuck:

$$(h,k).(1,1)=(h\varphi(k)(1),k(1))$$

and I want this to equal $(h,k)$ but I don't know what to do with the $\varphi(k)$. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since $\varphi\colon K\to \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ maps into the automorphism group of $H$, $\varphi(k)$ is an automorphism $H\to H$. As such it has to map the identity of $H$ to itself, so $\left(\varphi(k)\right)(1)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

For any group automorphism of some group G, the identity of G must be sent to itself. As $\phi(k)$ is an automorphism, we know that $\phi(k)(1)=1$. Thus $h\phi(k)(1)=h(1)=h$, as desired.